# Is there a standard for specifying weather-related preferences?

Tags: locale, standards, weather

I find over and over again that weather applications and web sites default to temperatures in °F and wind speeds in mph. My local standard (which is "local" in most of the world, I believe) is °C and m/s.  Is there any standard for specifying this?  The regular locale settings do not seem to have a slot for this.

(Some American weather sites "helpfully" convert mph to km/h but that's pretty useless. A codified standard would help them do the right thing, too.)

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: My primary platform is Linux but I use Windows and OSX, too. A proper standard should be platform-independent, or course.